# fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied

Tags: linux, macos, git, ssh

I am attempting to create a local git repository using a mounted linux drive (via SSH via ExpandDrive) from my mac using GitBox, however when I attempt to make a commit I continually receive this error.

fatal: error when closing sha1 file: Permission denied

I am not exactly sure how to fix this. From other searches, I have attempted to change the .git permissions and also tried using another Git GUI (Tower) but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried just command line approach using `git init`?

Comment: Did you tried a `git repo-config core.sharedRepository true` on the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the `.git` directory inside your repository, and what is inside. The data itself is in the `.git/objects` directory. An `ls -lR .git` should tell. It could be a *very* long list...

As it is some sort of external drive, it might be that the users don't match, or it is some filesystem that doesn't handle the file names used by git (unlikely, but I'd check for this too). Or it doesn't handle the permissions git it trying to give its files. I don't know how MacOS reacts on trying to close a file when there is no space, that also might explain the message. Or you might have run out of inodes. Can you create files there at all?